# Normalization data and show NA in R

Tags: r, normalization

I try to normalized the data in R, and it show N/A actually.

[Data before normalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZh4U.png)

[Data after normalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdlRI.png)

Is it the data is too small?
Or another problem? I have do some research and found that add `na.rm=T`, but where can I put?

`Normalized <-function(x) {(x-min(x,na.rm=T))/(max(x,na.rm=T)-min(x,na.rm=T))}`

If I do that, I found the outcome all is positive.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: There is a `scale` function.  Also, Can you show how you applied `Normalized`?  Is it `Normalized(df1$Price_trend)`?

Comment: For example, I used this code `NormalizedPrice<-as.data.frame(lapply(Price_trend,Normalized))`

Comment: Please show the reproducible example using `dput` instead of image as it is not easier to test the code.

Comment: If `Price_trend` is the column in your dataset (assuming that you `attach`ed the dataset), by using `lapply` it is looping through each of the observations and would likely result in NA (as there is only a single observation)